# How to attach a SQL Server database from the command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, command-line

Is it possible to enter a command line command (like in a batch file) to attach a detached database to SQL Server, in stead of opening the management studio and doing it in there?

Comment: can you explain with an example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to use: [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter
>   Transact-SQL statements, system
>   procedures, and script files at the
>   command prompt, in Query Editor in
>   SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file
>   or in an operating system (Cmd.exe)
>   job step of a SQL Server Agent job.
>   This utility uses OLE DB to execute
>   Transact-SQL batches.

Then use [CREATE DATABASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) to do the attach and [sp_detach_db (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx) to do the detach.  The [sp_attach_db (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) is going to be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Very nice. Worked like a charm. Did have to enable 'named pipes' to run SqlCmd, don't know why, but other than that: chapeau!

Comment: I have a batch file with this content:
`sqlcmd -Usa -PPASSWORD  -i"N:\SqlServer\attachexample_database.sql"`

and the content of the attachexample_database.sql is

`CREATE DATABASE example_database
      ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\example_database.mdf') 
      FOR ATTACH ;
      GO

GO`

Comment: and for detach I have this batch file `sqlcmd -Usa -PPASSWORD -i"N:\SqlServer\detachexample_database.sql"

and the content of the detachexample_database.sql is

`sp_detach_db example_database;`
GO

Answer (score 2):

If you need to specify the log file name: `USE master; GO; CREATE DATABASE DBNAME  ON   (   FILENAME = 'C:\DBFILE.mdf') LOG ON  (    FILENAME = 'C:\DBLOGFILE_log.ldf') FOR ATTACH; GO;` And to detach: `USE master; GO; EXEC sp_detach_db 'DBNAME', 'true'; GO;`

Answer (score 0):

Small gotcha, it won't tell you what is wrong when using sqlcmd and your mdf/ldf files are marked read-only. Make sure they are read-write.