# Attach Database without managment studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to attach my database in sql server without using managment studio how to do it?
Kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
sqlcmd -S Server\Instance

USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE databasename ON 
( FILENAME = N'path\databasename.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'path\databasename.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

Comment: database already exists and i want to attach only...but this script not attaching my sql database...

Answer (score 2):

```
Syntax of Query for attach

sp_attach_db [ @dbname= ] 'dbname'
    , [ @filename1= ] 'filename_n' [ ,...16 ]
```

Eg:

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks2012', 
    @filename1 = 
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf', 
    @filename2 = 
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2012_log.ldf';
```

> Syntax of Query detach

```
sp_detach_db [ @dbname= ] 'database_name' 
    [ , [ @skipchecks= ] 'skipchecks' ] 
    [ , [ @keepfulltextindexfile = ] 'KeepFulltextIndexFile' ]
```

Eg:

```
exec sp_detach_db @dbname='AdventureWorks2012'
    , @keepfulltextindexfile='true';
```

Comment: +1. Yeah. Helps to just check the documentation at times ;) The OP obviously never bothered to learn what he is using there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on what version of SQL Server, but recent ones you can use SQLCMD is you want to do it from the cmd line. See SO questions like

[How to attach a SQL Server database from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783862/how-to-attach-a-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line)

Which references [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx)